# Silverlight is not fetching data from my WCF RIA service

Tags: wcf, silverlight, ria

I just started learning Silverlight by walking through the labs posted on Channel9. When I tried to explore a little bit I found that my queries were not working as I thought they would.

To recreate what I have done you would need to create a new Silverlight Business application, create a data entity that is pointed to the Adventureworks LT db, and generate the web services for those entities (including edit).

I then simply drug a RichTextbox to Home.xaml and in Home.xaml.cs I added this code first to OnNavigatedTo and when that didn't work to the constructor.

```
    AdventureWorksDomainContext ctx = new AdventureWorksDomainContext();

    EntityQuery<Product> query =
        from p in ctx.GetProductsQuery()
        select p;
    LoadOperation<Product> loadOp = ctx.Load(query);

    var paragraph = new Paragraph();
    foreach (var product in loadOp.Entities)
    {
        paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = product.Name });
    }

    richTextBox1.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
```

When I run the page I never see loadOp.Entities contain a value and I only see the query I expect, go across the wire after all my code has been executed.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental and this will make more sense if I can find someone to explain it to me.

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to the how you are loading the data.  The actual Load operation is asynchronous, as is all Silverlight network calls.  You are callingt `ctx.Load(query)` and then immediately setting the paragraph to the entities.  You need to use a callback when `Load` is completed.  Something like this,

```
    AdventureWorksDomainContext ctx = new AdventureWorksDomainContext();

EntityQuery<Product> query =
    from p in ctx.GetProductsQuery()
    select p;
LoadOperation<Product> loadOp = ctx.Load(query,() => 
{
    var paragraph = new Paragraph();
    foreach (var product in loadOp.Entities)
    {
        paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = product.Name });
    }

    richTextBox1.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
});
```

Since you aren't using the entities directly in a binding and are just iterating them, you need to make sure you wait until they are loaded.  I can't remember the actual signature of the `Load` method, so you may need to modify my lambda to make it work.

Comment: What you are saying makes sense and that I need to treat it like an AJAX call. I will try when I get home tonight.